# How to stop creating public fork of a private fork in bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, fork

I have a private repo called ***PvtRepo*** in Bitbucket (part of my company. My bitbucket account has access to this repo)

Now i fork this ***PvtRepo*** into **my account** and call it as ***myproject/PvtFork***.

This ***PvtFork*** is not public and is not accessible outside; which is as expected.

But now  I try to fork the ***PvtFork*** ( and call it as ***PubFork***) and while forking i unselect the `Access Level: Private repository` check box. Surprisingly it works and creates a public fork called ***PubFork*** which is accessible to the whole world.

This is not desirable. If i remember correctly, I couldnt do this in github.

So is there a way to stop creating public fork of a private fork in bitbucket?

Or
Is there a way to stop 2 level forking altogether?

Or github is the only way to move forward, if I want to follow, "fork repo" style of working for my company?

Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

[Set Forking Permissions](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-repository-privacy-and-forking-options/)

Comment: i tried these instructions. they still allow one to create a public fork(pubFork) from a private fork (myproject/priFork). I know that the user has the choice to create a public or private fork. But i dont want to leave it to the user if admin has already made the primary repo (pvtRepo) as private.